# Not seeing count labels on bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I'd like to add count labels to a simple bar chart. I've tried the following code with and without `y=count`; it runs without error but doesn't display the labels:

```
Class <- ggplot(asteroid, aes(x=class, y=count, fill = class, labels = TRUE))

Class + 
geom_bar() + 
ggtitle('Frequency of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Asteroids by Class') +
xlab('Class Based on Solar System Location') + 
labs(caption = '(*) indicates a potentially hazardous object') +
scale_fill_discrete(labels=c('Amor*','Apollo','Apollo*','Aten','Aten*','Interior Earth Object*'))
```

I have also tried this:

```
Class <- ggplot(asteroid, aes(x=class, y=count, fill = class))
    
Class + 
geom_bar() + 
ggtitle('Frequency of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Asteroids by Class') +
xlab('Class Based on Solar System Location') + 
labs(caption = '(*) indicates a potentially hazardous object') +
scale_fill_discrete(labels=c('Amor*','Apollo','Apollo*','Aten','Aten*','Interior Earth Object*'))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
geom_text(aes(label = count), vjust = 0)
```

but I'm met with the following error:

```
"Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = count. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?"
```

Obviously R is thinking "count" to be `count()` but I can't seem to find a way to work around this. Have tried using freq instead, Count, etc. Those were long shots but I'm a bit stumped.

Edit: Here's a snapshot of the character variable I'm working with:

```
> head(dput(asteroid$class))
> [1] "APO*" "APO*" "APO*" "APO*" "APO*" "APO*"
```

And the dataset:

> ```
>    head(dput(asteroid))
> ```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 17
  Object...1      `Epoch (TDB)` `a (AU)`     e `i (deg)` `w (deg)` `Node (deg)` `M (deg)` `q (AU)` `Q (AU)` `P (yr)`
  <chr>                   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 1566 Icarus             57800     1.08 0.827     22.8       31.4         88.0      216.    0.187     1.97     1.12
2 1620 Geographos         57800     1.25 0.335     13.3      277.         337.       104.    0.828     1.66     1.39
3 1862 Apollo             55249     1.47 0.560      6.35     286.          35.7      175.    0.647     2.29     1.78
4 1981 Midas              57800     1.78 0.650     39.8      268.         357.       173.    0.621     2.93     2.37
5 2101 Adonis             57800     1.87 0.765      1.33      43.4        350.       235.    0.441     3.31     2.57
6 2102 Tantalus           57800     1.29 0.299     64.0       61.6         94.4      355.    0.904     1.68     1.47
# … with 6 more variables: `H (mag)` <dbl>, `MOID (AU)` <dbl>, ref <dbl>, class <chr>, Object...16 <chr>,
#   Hazardous <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated with your data sample.

`asteroid` is uncounted, so I've added `count(class)`. I've added a second version where the data is uncounted.

```r
library(tidyverse)

asteroid <- data.frame(class = c("apo",'ieo','amor','aten', 'amor'))

# Counted
asteroid |> 
  count(class) |> 
  ggplot(aes(class, n, fill = class)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  ggtitle('Frequency of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Asteroids by Class') + 
  xlab('Class Based on Solar System Location') + 
  labs(caption = '() indicates a potentially hazardous object') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = n), vjust = 0)
```

[image]

```r
# Uncounted
asteroid |> 
  ggplot(aes(class, fill = class)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  ggtitle('Frequency of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Asteroids by Class') + 
  xlab('Class Based on Solar System Location') + 
  labs(caption = '() indicates a potentially hazardous object') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = 'count', vjust = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok tried that..."Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?"

Comment: Did you replace the tribble() with asteroid so you have asteroid |> ggplot( … etc?  If you still have a problem could you show what you actually ran?

Comment: Ok ran this:  
library("tidyverse")
    asteroid |>
      ggplot(aes(class, count, fill = class, labels = TRUE)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
      ggtitle('Frequency of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Asteroids by Class') + 
      xlab('Class Based on Solar System Location') + 
      labs(caption = '() indicates a potentially hazardous object') + 
      scale_fill_discrete(labels=c('Amor','Apollo','Apollo*','Aten','Aten*','Interior Earth Object*'))+
      geom_text(aes(label = count), vjust = 0)

Comment: and got this: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = count. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?

Comment: Could you run this `head(dput(asteroid))` and paste the result? It will give me a sample of your data.

Comment: The above should work for you.

Comment: wow just a <count(class)>. So simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: Either pre-count then `geom_col` with `x = class` and `y = n`, or uncounted (see second example) with `geom_bar`, no `y`, and `geom_text` needs special treatment.